# Elasticsearch 6.1 Java API search issue

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-6

I am using ES - 6.1 and corresponding java version of the api. I was able to index the data using the java API. I validated this via kibana. All the mappings were correctly saved but an error comes up when I try to search. Even the most basic search returns me an empty collection.

```
// client is a reference to the TransportClient instance
SearchResponse searchResponse = this.client.prepareSearch(index).get().
```

When I try get the fields, by getFields() and further do a getField(key) I get a null pointer exception. I tried troubleshooting and saw that in the response there are no objects being returned. Following is the basic search I am doing.

```
// index is the index I am interested to search under.
SearchResponse searchResponse = this.client.prepareSearch(index).get();
```

This is an issue I see when I tried migrating my code to latest version from 1.7.3 Java API. Earlier, there are no issues found with our implementation.

I have read through quite a few articles on changes that have come across for this but no solution that is found applicable in my case.

I have re-indexed my data with each of the property set with stored mapping. I still do not get response with the fields I am interested in. The fields Keyset is still a null value

Following is the mapping sample.

```
"street": {
    "type": "text",
    "store": true
},
"country": {
    "type": "text",
    "store": true
},
"city": {
    "type": "text",
    "store": true
}
---------------Some more fields--------------
```

Attaching the screenshot of my variables from debugger.
    }

Here is response for each hit I get when I troubleshoot. I am getting the right number of hits in that index . Attaching the screenshot of my variables from debugger. **hits** is the variable containing response from following piece of code.

```
hits = searchResponse.getHits()
```

[Debugger log for the values "hits" hold](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LeGLr.png)

Thank You for the help.

-Ajit

Answer (score 0):

I identified the issue to be lying with the search methods.

Unlike the previous versions, the new version will get the hits in a map in a different method.

```
//in previous version (1.7.3)
hit.getFields() 
// in new version (6.1.0)
hit.getSourceAsMap()
```

Further on, we can deserialize the response just the way we had been doing it earlier.

Here is [link](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/elasticsearch-6-1-0-java-api-search-issues/113581) to elasticsearch forum which has all the details. Thanks for the help.

-Ajit